# Sorting Ballerina record type array by an attribute?

Tags: arrays, sorting, record, ballerina

I have an array of following record type

```
public type Employee record {
    string email;
    string status;
    ...
};
```

I need to sort the array by email.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to use a query expression like below:

```
Employee[] employees = [];
Employee[] sortedEmployees = from var emp in employees
    order by emp.email
    select emp;
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```
Employee[] sorted = sortedEmployees.sort(array:ASCENDING, (item) => item.email);
```